# dockerfile: mv command not working as expected

Tags: docker, dockerfile

When I run this command on my linux terminal::

```
mv -nv -t path/to/dest -- path/to/src/!(*abc*).txt
```

It moves all .txt files in src to dest, except those which have abc in their name, and this is what I want.

But when I use this command in dockerfile:

```
RUN curl ....
    ....
    && mv -nv -t path/to/dest -- path/to/src/!(*abc*).txt
```

I get error:

```
/bin/sh: 1: Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

Why this difference in behaviour?

Edit:

```
ARG IMAGE_NAME=eclipse-temurin
ARG IMAGE_TAG=11-jre
FROM ${IMAGE_NAME}:${IMAGE_TAG}
ARG MAINTAINER="Apache NiFi <dev@nifi.apache.org>"
LABEL maintainer="${MAINTAINER}"
LABEL site="https://nifi.apache.org"

ARG UID=1000
ARG GID=0
ARG NIFI_VERSION_PREV=1.10.0
ARG NIFI_VERSION=1.22.0
ARG BASE_URL=https://archive.apache.org/dist
ARG MIRROR_BASE_URL=${MIRROR_BASE_URL:-${BASE_URL}}
ARG DISTRO_PATH_PREV=${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}
ARG DISTRO_PATH=${DISTRO_PATH:-${NIFI_VERSION}}
ARG NIFI_BINARY_PATH_PREV=/nifi/${DISTRO_PATH_PREV}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip
ARG NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH_PREV=/nifi/${DISTRO_PATH_PREV}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip
ARG NIFI_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${DISTRO_PATH}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}
ARG NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH=${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH:-/nifi/${DISTRO_PATH}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip}

ENV NIFI_BASE_DIR=/opt/nifi
ENV NIFI_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-current
ENV NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-current
ENV NIFI_PID_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/run
ENV NIFI_LOG_DIR=${NIFI_HOME}/logs

ADD sh/ ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/
RUN chmod -R +x ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/scripts/*.sh

# Setup NiFi user and create necessary directories
RUN groupadd -g ${GID} nifi || groupmod -n nifi `getent group ${GID} | cut -d: -f1` \
    && useradd --shell /bin/bash -u ${UID} -g ${GID} -m nifi \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && chown -R nifi:0 ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y jq xmlstarlet procps unzip \
    && apt-get -y autoremove \
    && apt-get clean autoclean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/*

# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi Toolkit binary.
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_TOOLKIT_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_TOOLKIT_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-toolkit-${NIFI_VERSION}

# Download, validate, and expand Apache NiFi binary.
RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}-bin.zip \
    && mv ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION} ${NIFI_HOME} \
    && mkdir -p ${NIFI_HOME}/conf \
    && ln -s ${NIFI_HOME} ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION}

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

RUN curl -fSL ${MIRROR_BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH_PREV} -o ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip \
    && echo "$(curl ${BASE_URL}/${NIFI_BINARY_PATH_PREV}.sha256) *${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip" | sha256sum -c - \
    && unzip ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip -d ${NIFI_BASE_DIR} \
    && rm ${NIFI_BASE_DIR}/nifi-${NIFI_VERSION_PREV}-bin.zip \
    && mv -nv -t /opt/nifi/nifi-current/lib/ -- /opt/nifi/nifi-1.10.0/lib/!(*jetty*).nar


VOLUME ${NIFI_LOG_DIR} \
       ${NIFI_HOME}/conf \
       ${NIFI_HOME}/repositories \
       ${NIFI_HOME}/flow \
       /content \
       /spool

# Clear nifi-env.sh in favour of configuring all environment variables in the Dockerfile
RUN echo "#!/bin/sh\n" > $NIFI_HOME/bin/nifi-env.sh

# Web HTTP(s) & Socket Site-to-Site Ports
EXPOSE 8080 8443 10000 8000

WORKDIR ${NIFI_HOME}

# Apply configuration and start NiFi
#
# We need to use the exec form to avoid running our command in a subshell and omitting signals,
# thus being unable to shut down gracefully:
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint
#
# Also we need to use relative path, because the exec form does not invoke a command shell,
# thus normal shell processing does not happen:
# https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#exec-form-entrypoint-example
ENTRYPOINT ["../scripts/start.sh"]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default shell is `sh`, whereas you want to use `bash`. To fix this, change the default shell to bash in the Dockerfile:

```
SHELL ["/bin/bash"]
```

this will change the default shell for all subsequent `RUN` commands.